# What are the main uses for the NPM package.json file?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I read from [here](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/npm/what-is-the-file-package-json) that the dependencies in the package.json file allow people to install the dependencies if they install your project through npm-

> Finally, the dependencies field is used to list all the dependencies
>   of your project that are available on npm. When someone installs your
>   project through npm, all the dependencies listed will be installed as
>   well. Additionally, if someone runs npm install in the root directory
>   of your project, it will install all the dependencies to
>   ./node_modules.

Where will all the dependencies be installed to if someone doesn't run npm install in the root directory of your project?

Also, what if they choose to clone this project through Github instead? It would be ready to go anyway, right? Then at that point what is the purpose of the package.json file besides giving the user meta data about the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where will all the dependencies be installed to if someone doesn't run npm install in the root directory of your project?

If by that you mean 'where will they be installed if you run the command in a different directory', NPM will search upwards through the parent directories until it finds `package.json`, and then install the dependencies in a `node_modules` folder next to that file. I.E. they'll always end up in the project root.

> Also, what if they choose to clone this project through Github instead? It would be ready to go anyway, right? Then at that point what is the purpose of the package.json file besides giving the user meta data about the project?

This isn't the case! Node projects just about always have a `.gitignore` file which explicitly excludes `node_modules` from being committed to version control, and expect you to run `npm install` after downloading the source.

There's very few good reasons to have your dependencies in your GitHub repository - as long as a project adheres to [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) (the vast majority of packages do), `npm install` will never cause incompatible versions to be downloaded, and if you absolutely need to lock down the versions of your dependencies, you can just use [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap).

**EDIT:** As Matt's comment very helpfully pointed out, there's several features of NPM that go beyond simple metadata - the one I probably get the most use out of is [Scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), which allow you to create project-specific aliases for command-line operations.

An example of where this has come in handy for me is running the Webpack development server - it's installed locally to my project in the `devDependencies` (which you can do using the `--save-dev` option when installing a package), so if I was doing it manually, I would have to type something along the lines of:

```
"./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server" --inline --hot
```

Which quite frankly, would be a bit of a pain. Instead, I can just add this to my package.json (note that `node_modules/.bin` is automatically added to the system path when using an NPM script, so you don't need to type that every time):

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot"
}
```

And then all I have to run is:

```
npm run dev
```

Beyond this simple use-case, there's also several 'special' script names which are automatically called upon certain events - for example, `prepublish` is run before publishing a package to the registry.

Comment: I'd add [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and [config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) are two uses of package.json that go beyond simple metadata.

Comment: Good point! I'll edit my answer to elaborate on those a little.

Comment: @JoeClay so the package.json file isn't necessary for you to use the packages in your node_modules folder, right? after you install those packages, you can npm ___ to use them. the package.json is more for scripts, config, metadata, and most importantly helping other folks later on install all the packages that's necessary for the project since those modules would not be uploaded due to the git.ignore file

Answer (score 0):

Each Node.js project must contain at least one package.json file, usually located in the root directory of your project. This file identifies the project and lists the packages your project depends on, making your build reproducible.

You can create a package.json file by using a text editor, but the quickest way is to run the npm init command and pass it the -y flag

```
  npm init -y
```